# Could a range-based for loop overflow at fewer than uint64 (or max size uint) iterations?

Tags: c++

I am iterating a (potentially) massive number of times, I'm currently using

```cpp
for (uint_fast64_t i = 0; i < x.length(); i++){
```

just so there's no risk of overflow at all.  Does clang-tidy's suggestion:

```cpp
for (char i : x){
```

increase the possibility of overflow?  (Is this compiler/implementation dependent?)

Comment: Overflow of what? Range-based loop doesn't use a variable of integral type for iteration, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Suppose the type returned by `x.length()` is an integer greater than 64 bits.
According to the C++ spec; Uint integers, when all bits of the number are set to 1 (2**64-1), the next increment will write 0 to the uint variable. Not overflow but unexpected happens.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik From what is exposed yea, but how internally can it iterate without incrementing a number

Comment: Iterators is how.

Comment: An iterator still must iterate something

Comment: Well, obviously, the implementation would make sure to provide iterators that are actually capable of, you know, iterating over the container. How it does that is an internal implementation detail.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hopefully but I didn't see anything in the spec of `std::string` that guaranteed that

Comment: The spec guarantees that, for any container, `begin()` and `end()` produce a valid range. The definition of a valid range is that the start iterator, after being incremented zero or more times, eventually becomes equal to the end iterator.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Okay didn't see that, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically this will be compiler-dependent, but it's *very* unlikely to cause problems. [Range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) desugar to iterators (`begin()` and `end()` calls), not indices, and any datatype whose iterators can't handle indexing into their own data is a silly datatype.

In practice, on my current machine, `std::string::iterator` is defined to be a custom type called `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, std::basic_string>`, which is more or less a thin wrapper around `char*`. So if your data can be referenced with a *pointer*, then it'll work. And if your data is being stored in computer RAM, then it can be (and is currently being) referenced by a pointer.

On the other hand, if you're dealing with truly gargantuan data like a terabyte file on some tape machine, then you're not storing that whole thing in an `std::string` anyway. And you're accessing it using a custom class whose `::iterator` reads the data in intelligent chunks. So in this case, the range-based for loop will actually be *smarter* than the index-based one.

All in all, take the `clang-tidy` suggestion. For built-in standard library types, it will not increase the chance of overflow, and for exotic types that wrap extremely large (non-RAM) data, it'll actually *improve* your chances of being able to iterate over the data.